# bdb db open database cannot be opened err 22. restore from backup

Tags: database, unix, cmd, ldap, openldap

I am trying to setup **OpenLDAP** on my windows machine.But i am facing ERROR and due to which I am not able to proceed with the setup.
Below is the ERROR sample.

```
bdb db open database cannot be opened err 22. restore from backup
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've hit the same error. After recover database, it works now. On Windows, BDB recover tool db_recover.exe can be found in DBDTools directory under your OpenLDAP install path. The command to recover your db is like this:

```
db_recover -v -h %YOUR_OPENLDAP_DATA_DIR%
```

And this is link I refered:
[LDAP server fails to start because of a corrupted database on FreeBSD](http://zewaren.net/site/node/97)

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can help you write answers that will be accepted and upvoted.

Comment: zhon Thanks! I'll check the doc. Kshitij Dasture, very happy it helps.